# In Windows CMD command to close applications not found in two seperate tasklist text files

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to create a .bat file that will close applications opened in the background. To do this my initial idea was to first tasklist to a txt document when the computer just turned on, then after I used some applications the program would tasklist again, and close all applications that are not turned on in both the initial tasklist and final tasklist. I wrote the code making the two tasklists, but am unsure how to close the applications? How  could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that closing all the background applications would be a good decision . Theres the risk of closing some critical process , necessary for the system . That could end in a System Crash (redirection to the BSOD) or could decrease the perfomances of the computer .

Another challenge would be analyzing the assembly of each application running to see if it contains a background worker ( impossible cause almost every application have an encrypted assembly , and these usually have not similar frameworks ) .

I don't even think there is a library to do that .